# Rspec Testing Method That Retrieves Object from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am testing a method which takes a token that represents an object in the database, and retrieves it.

I am trying to test that using rspec. How would I insert that object into the database first? I know I should be mocking it, but when I do, how would I then make that method access that mock as opposed to hit the database (as what it's written to do)?

Answer (score 0):

Stub your retrieval method to return the mock you wanted. Or you could insert it into the database, retrieve it and then stub the retrieval method to get the object you just retrieved. It might be simpler just to retrieve the object and not mess around with mocks at all, especially if it is really complex SQL or something that is getting the object (that is probably more important logic to test).